# Matching elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have two numpy arrays.  The first, Z1, is about 300,000 rows long and 3 columns wide.  The second, Z2, is about 200,000 rows and 300 columns.  Each row of each Z1 and Z2 has an identifying number (10-digit).  Z2 contains a subset of the items in Z1, and I want to match the rows in Z2 with their partners in Z1 based on the 10-digit identifying number, then take columns 2 and 3 from Z1 and insert them at the end of Z2 in their appropriate rows.

Neither Z1 nor Z2 are in any particular order.

The only way I've come up with to do this is by iterating over the arrays, which takes hours.  Is there a better way to do this in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand from your question that the 10-digit identifier is stored in column 1, right?

This is not very easy to follow, a lot of indirection going on, but in the end `unsorted_insert` has the row numbers of where in `Z1` each identifier of `Z2` is

```
sort_idx = np.argsort(Z1[:, 0])
sorted_insert = np.searchsorted(Z1[:, 0], Z2[:, 0], sorter=sort_idx)
# The following is equivalent to unsorted_insert = sort_idx[sorted_insert] but faster
unsorted_insert = np.take(sort_idx, sorted_insert)
```

So now all we need to do is to fetch the last two columns of those rows and stack them to the `Z2` array:

```
new_Z2 = np.hstack((Z2, Z1[unsorted_insert, 1:]))
```

---

A made up example that runs with no issues:

```
import numpy as np

z1_rows, z1_cols = 300000, 3
z2_rows, z2_cols = 200000, 300

z1 = np.arange(z1_rows*z1_cols).reshape(z1_rows, z1_cols)

z2 = np.random.randint(10000, size=(z2_rows, z2_cols))
z2[:, 0] = z1[np.random.randint(z1_rows, size=(z2_rows,)), 0]

sort_idx = np.argsort(z1[:, 0])
sorted_insert = np.searchsorted(z1[:, 0], z2[:, 0], sorter=sort_idx)
# The following is equivalent to unsorted_insert = sort_idx[sorted_insert] but faster
unsorted_insert = np.take(sort_idx, sorted_insert)
new_z2 = np.hstack((z2, z1[unsorted_insert, 1:]))
```

Haven't timed it, but the whole thing seems to complete in under a couple of seconds.

Comment: this seems promising, but it's throwing me an error:  

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 807, in searchsorted
return searchsorted(v,side)
ValueError: expected nonempty string for keyword 'side'

This seems to not occur when I put parentheses around 'Z1[:,0], Z2[:,0], but then it takes forever to run and doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Ah, but it does give another error, which is about your line 2, with the parens:
sorted_insert = np.searchsorted((Z1[:, 0], Z2[:, 0]), sort_idx)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 806, in searchsorted
return _wrapit(a, 'searchsorted', v, side)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @DathosPachy I have added some made up sample data to my answer, and I can run it without any significant issue. What version of numpy are you using? Is updating to the latest 1.7 an option?

Comment: I'm running 1.6.2.  I'll see about upgrading, since the same error seems to be cropping up in the same place.  Thanks!

Comment: @DathosPachy You can try to simply add the `side` keyword in the call to `np.searchsorted`: `sorted_insert = np.searchsorted(z1[:, 0], z2[:, 0], side='left', sorter=sort_idx)`

Comment: now it's telling me that    sorter    is an unexpected keyword, so I eliminate that, and it tells me that the keyword argument needs to go after.  If I put    sort_idx    first, then it tells me I'm giving multiple arguments for    'side'    , and if I put it after it tells me that I'm giving 4 arguments instead of the required 3.  So I may try and upgrade tomorrow...

Comment: I am using 1.7 syntax, not really sure what 1.6.2 is, but I think you want `sorted_insert = np.searchsorted(z1[sort_idx, 0], z2[:, 0], side='left')`.